# can not deploy django scikit learn project on heroku, slug size too large error

Tags: python, django, numpy, heroku, scikit-learn

I am trying to deploy a pet project on heroku, but keep getting error: "slug size is 314 mb, maximum limit is 300 mb". I tried purging cache but to no effect. it's a fairly small project, I am listing the requirements.txt file here, if it helps. Any suggestion on deploying it properly will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
requirements.txt
Django==1.9.6
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
django-registration-redux==1.4
gunicorn==19.4.5
psycopg2==2.6.1
whitenoise==2.0.6
dj-database-url==0.4.0

conda-requirements.txt
numpy
scipy
scikit-learn
```

using conda buildpack: https://github.com/kennethreitz/conda-buildpack

Comment: Numpy and scipy are large. Probably not too many people use packages like that with Heroku.

Comment: any suggestions about where and how can I deploy my site with these packages?

Comment: Yes, IMO, AWS is the best solution. Given you want the simplicity of Heroku, you should try to use AWS's Elastic Beanstalk, which gives you a lot of the same simplicity, but at the same time, with more ways to have better control. In this case, I would suggest trying to set it up on top for docker from the get go. In fact, I created and use a docker image for video processing which has these packages, and works on AWS EB: https://github.com/ampervue/docker-ffmpeg. You need something similar to that. Sorry, a proper answer won't fit as a comment here, but hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i'll try it out

Comment: Solved it, just needed to add nomkl to the conda-requirements.txt file to get the slugsize down.